# Folders path with new version of QField

Tags: qfield, path

Through the QField app version 1.9.5 I imported some projects, with the related data, created with QGIS. The path I used to import the shapefiles and projects created during the field work was the following: Android> data> ch.opengis.qfield> files> share. These folders were automatically created by the app upon its download.

Currently, the version available for downoload is QField 1.9.6. After this update the folders path, created automatically with the previous version, is no longer visible.

Could you tell me the new path in which insert the project with its folders, in the latest version of the app?

Answer (score 1):

I think, Android 11 has removed access to the `Android/data` folder. I am unsure why it happened to you with the QField update.

Anyway. I recommend you to use a folder on the internal storage for your QField projects. Like `/storage/emulated/0/qfield_projects`.
The `Android/data` folders will be deleted anyway when uninstalling the app, which can be very unwanted.